# Porting from DXR/HLSL to Vulkan Ray Tracing Extension/GLSL

Tags: raytracing, glsl, vulkan, hlsl, raymarching

I am working on the port of a demo from DXR to Vulkan Ray Tracing extension using GLSL.
In DXR/HLSL space, there are *RayTMin()* and R*ayTCurrent()* functions to retrieve the starting and the current end point of the ray  (*Origin + (Direction * RayTMin)* and  *Origin + (Direction * RayTCurrent)*, respectively).
In Vulkan RT/GLSL space, one specifies the **tMin** and **tMax** values in the  *traceRayEXT(...)* call, but how does one retrieve the "**current t**" and "**t min**" values in an intersection shader?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [document](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/master/extensions/ext/GLSL_EXT_ray_tracing.txt), one should be able to extract those values through
*gl_RayTminEXT* and *gl_RayTmaxEXT* **GLSL** built-ins for intersection shader.

Further comments are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand [GLSL_EXT_ray_tracing.txt](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/master/extensions/ext/GLSL_EXT_ray_tracing.txt), `gl_RayTmaxEXT` contains the **current t** in intersection shaders, due to the following pieces of information given in [GLSL_EXT_ray_tracing.txt](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/master/extensions/ext/GLSL_EXT_ray_tracing.txt):

```
 In the intersection language, built-in variables are declared as follows

    ...

    // Ray parameters
    in          float  gl_RayTminEXT;
    in volatile float  gl_RayTmaxEXT;
    in          uint   gl_IncomingRayFlagsEXT;

    ...
```

=> due to the `volatile` declaration of `gl_RayTmaxEXT`.

Also the description of `bool reportIntersectionEXT(float hitT, uint hitKind);` remarks that `gl_RayTmaxEXT` is not constant:

> If the intersection is not ignored in the
> any-hit shader, <hitT> is committed as the new gl_RayTmaxEXT value of the
> current ray,  is committed as the new value for gl_HitKindEXT, and
> true is returned.